# Further modifying regular expression for password

Tags: javascript, regex

How would you modify this regex to only allow letters and numbers?

I thought by putting that it must have at least 2 uppercase letters, lowercase letters and digits, that it would limit the expression to just those types of characters.  But it allows unwanted characters like tildes and such.

```
/^[\s]*((?=([^\s]*\d){2,})(?=([^\s]*[a-z]){2,})(?=([^\s]*[A-Z]){2,})[^\s]{8,16})[\s]*$/
```

Comment: So, in English, what does that pattern do (or ideally do)?  Match any string that contains 2 uppercase letters, 2 lower and 2 digits, in any order?

Comment: What sort of letters? Just A-Z and a-z or also other letters?

Comment: One thing to consider is that non-alphanumeric characters make passwords much more secure. Is there really a good reason to limit the password space?

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand, yes that is what is supposed to do, but I'm trying to limit it to just those characters as well.  Yes just a-z,A_Z, and digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to do it using a few needles.  [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/EZKSC/)

```
alert( verify('AbcdeFghij123') );
alert( verify('Abcdeghij123') ); // Only 1 capital
alert( verify('AbcdeFghij') ); // No numbers
alert( verify('ABCDEF123') ); // No lowercase
alert( verify('Abc~~ghij123') ); // Tilde
alert( verify('') ); // Blank

function verify(pass) {
    return /^[A-Za-z0-9]+$/.test(pass)
        && /[A-Z][^A-Z]*[A-Z]/.test(pass)
        && /[a-z][^a-z]*[a-z]/.test(pass)
        && /[0-9][^0-9]*[0-9]/.test(pass);
}
```

If you want to limit the size to being between X and Y replace `/^[A-Za-z0-9]+$/` with `/^[A-Za-z0-9]{X,Y}$/`.  Pretty simple, eh?

Comment: Yup this will do it. But instead of using the dot-star, you can improve the efficiency by changing: `/[A-Z].*[A-Z]/` to: `/[A-Z][^A-Z]*[A-Z]/` and: `/[a-z].*[a-z]/` to: `/[a-z][^a-z]*[a-z]/`, and so on. This _"free-flowing regex"_ technique reduces the required backtracking and results in faster matching and non-matching.

Comment: Thanks @ridgerunner.  I never know about those optimizations.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see a way for a single regex to count the uppercase letter amid the other lowercase letters and digits.  As they say, regular expressions can't count.

So, I think your solution will entail a regex to determine that the appropriate *kinds* of letters are present and then in a separate step you can count the upper-case characters afterwards:

```
/[A-Za-z0-9]{8,16}/
```

For the subsequent steps (validating that the string has at least two uppercase characters, two lowercase letters, and two digits), try these three regexes:

```
/[A-Z].*[A-Z]/
/[0-9].*[0-9]/
/[a-z].*[a-z]/
```

Any string that matches all four regexes will be one that meets your password criteria.

That being said, it may be easier to make a function without regexes and just do simple character counts in a loop.

FWIW, a good tool for exploring alternate ways of building a regex is to visit http://txt2re.com

Comment: I agree with Raymond - I've never understood why people are obsessed with making a regex to implement all their password rules when a few lines of javascript can be written much faster than trying to sort out the OP's regex mess and the code will also end up much more readable.  The goal should be the fastest way to get clean, reliable and maintainable code, not the longest way to get an obtuse regex that solves the problem in one line.

Comment: Who says regex can't count? For me, a single regex solution _is_ readable and maintainable (and _fast!_). I do agree, however, that all non-trivial regexes should be thoroughly commented for maintainability. For JavaScript, (which does not allow the `'x'` free-spacing mode modifier), I'll place the original commented version of the regex in a '/*comment*/'. See my one regex solution (which is faster than the other solutions BTW). Frequently, the goal is _fast execution speed_.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a tested function that will validate a password with your requirements:

```js
/*  Validate a password string that has:
    * From 8 to 16 letters and digits.
    * Optional leading and trailing whitespace.
    * At least 2 uppercase letters.
    * At least 2 lowercase letters.
    * At least 2 decimal digits.
    Here is the regex in (PHP) free-spacing mode with comments:
    $re = '/# Validate password has 2 upper, 2 lower and 2 digits.
        ^                        # Anchor to start of string.
        (?=(?:[^A-Z]*[A-Z]){2})  # Assert 2 uppercase letters.
        (?=(?:[^a-z]*[a-z]){2})  # Assert 2 lowercase letters.
        (?=(?:[^0-9]*[0-9]){2})  # Assert 2 decimal digits.
        \s*                      # Allow leading whitespace.
        ([A-Za-z0-9]{8,16})      # $1: Password 8-16 of [A-Za-z0-9]
        \s*                      # Allow trailing whitespace.
        $                        # Anchor to end of string.
        /x';
    If valid password, return password trimmed of leading and trailing whitespace.
    If invalid password, return empty string.
*/
function validatePassword(text)  {
    var re = /^(?=(?:[^A-Z]*[A-Z]){2})(?=(?:[^a-z]*[a-z]){2})(?=(?:[^0-9]*[0-9]){2})\s*([A-Za-z0-9]{8,16})\s*$/;
    var m = text.match(re);
    if (m) return m[1];     // If valid, return trimmed password
    return '';              // If not valid, return empty string
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Pretty simple really. This will do the trick.

```
/^(?=.*[a-z].*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z].*[A-Z])(?=.*\d.*\d)[a-zA-Z0-9]{8,16}$/
```

Requires: 2 numbers, 2 lowercase, 2 uppercase, min. 8 & max. 16 chars total

Answer **EXPLAINED**...

```
// Matches/requires 2 lowercase (a-z)
(?=.*[a-z].*[a-z])

// Matches/requires 2 uppercase (A-Z)
(?=.*[A-Z].*[A-Z])

// Matches/requires 2 digits (0-9)
(?=.*\d.*\d)

// Matches/requires all 3 conditions and sets minimum string length of 8 and maximum string legth of 16
[a-zA-Z0-9]{8,16}
```