# RegExp for minimum 4 numbers and minimum 1 character

Tags: regex

I'm trying to test if an input has at least 4 number and 1 character in it. I have this which works, but only when the characters are in the order `0000a`, I wanted it to match no matter what the order, so `00a00`, `a0000`, `aa00a00a` would all match the pattern.

```
[0-9]{4,}[a-zA-Z]{1,}
```

What do I need to change? I tried `[a-zA-Z0-9]{5,}` but then things like `aaaaa` and `00012` matched, which is no good.

Comment: Have you looked at these kind of questions: [Regex for alpanumeric with at least 1 number and 1 character](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7684815/regex-for-alpanumeric-with-at-least-1-number-and-1-character), or [check if string contains both number and letter (at least)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429847/check-if-string-contains-both-number-and-letter-at-least) ?

Comment: Thanks for the link, I've got this which seems to work `^(?=.*[0-9]{4,})(?=.*[a-zA-Z]+)([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$`, I'll have a read up and see what exactly a positive lookahead actually does.

Comment: Positive look ahead are usually a very easy way to add (possibly many of) these kind of conditions to a single regex. Your `^(?=.*[0-9]{4,})(?=.*[a-zA-Z]+)([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$` attempt wouldn't match `4a444` though, you can fix it with `^(?=(?:.*\d){4})(?=.*[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9]+$` ([Demo](http://regex101.com/r/hR3aN7)) or use @falsetru's shorter answer.

Comment: @Robin: Oh sorry, read it wrong.

Comment: See also my answer to a similar question: [Further modifying regular expression for password](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8461455/433790). Questions like this one get asked a _LOT_.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using lookahead assertion:

```
(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(.*?\d){4,}
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/cZoYPZnwjKQJ76a5)

Comment: On Debuggex it works fine, but in my code it seems to fail each time, I've used it like `var regex = new RegExp('(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(.*?\d){4,}');`, then I'm using `regex.test(myStringVarHere);` Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @TomHart, Use regular expression literal: `var regex = /(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(.*?\d){4,}/`

Comment: @TomHart, because `'\d' == 'd'`; it matches a letter `d` instead of a digit (`\d`). You should escape the backslash if you want to use string literal form.

Comment: Yes, +1. But, instead of using the ubiquitous (and frequently not necessary) _dot-star_ it is typically more efficient to use a more precise expression like so: `^(?=[^a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z])(\D*\d){4,}`. I've also added a start-of-string-anchor to make the non-matching cases much more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

If the formal rules are:

```
"Numbers >= 4 AND characters == 1"
```

you'll find no way with regex because the character could be everywhere. In this case you'd need some kind of Pushdown automaton or an algorithm with a counter.

If the rule is
`"Numbers == 4 AND characters == 1"` the following should (not easy to read) may work:

```
([a-zA-Z][0-9]{4,})|([0-9][a-zA-Z][0-9]{3,})|([0-9]{2,}[a-zA-Z][0-9]{2,})|([0-9]{3,}[a-zA-Z][0-9])|([0-9]{4,}[a-zA-Z])
```

And if the ruls is
"(Numbers + characters) >= 4 AND characters >= 1" this may work:

```
([a-zA-Z]([a-zA-Z]|[0-9]){4,})|(([a-zA-Z]|[0-9])[a-zA-Z]([a-zA-Z]|[0-9]){3,})|(([a-zA-Z]|[0-9]){2,}[a-zA-Z]([a-zA-Z]|[0-9]){2,})|(([a-zA-Z]|[0-9]){3,}[a-zA-Z]([a-zA-Z]|[0-9]))|(([a-zA-Z]|[0-9]){4,}[a-zA-Z])
```

But because of bot solutions are quite ugly I'd suggest to use none of them. Implement a small algorithm would be easier and more readable.